# how to display a image outside the project using webpack (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

"I have a problem: I can't display an image that is located on a different disk than my project, and Webpack doesn't seem to like it. Moving the elements into my development project is not an option since it's about 1 TB in size. The issue likely arises from Webpack because the image I need to display depends on variables selected by the user, and it involves dynamic searching. As a result, the application fails to compile, stating that it can't find the module."

I have tried some things, and it works like this:

```
 <img src={require(`:T\store50\img250.png`)} />
```

. However, when I try to do dynamic things, especially with variables chosen by the user, the compilation fails, and Webpack crashes.

For example:

```
 <img src={require(`:T\store${store.id}\img${store.idImg}.png`)} />
```

I have attempted to use a hook or a variable, but it doesn't work, or maybe I did it incorrectly.

I believe the issue likely arises from Webpack. The problem is that I can't inspect the Webpack configurations because I created my project using the 'create-react-app' command.